# Error in parse_aws_s3_response, Forbidden (http 403)

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I a
I'm trying to use aws.s3 library to load data into S3. Below is my code below:

```
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = ".............",
       "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "...............",
       "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "......")
```

view bucket:

```
get_bucket(bucket = "....",
           check_region = FALSE,
           verbose = TRUE)
```

The code above works and contents of the bucket is returned.

save object to s3:

```
s3save(data, 
       object = ".....",
       bucket = ".....")
```

Error return:

```
List of 4
$ Code     : chr "AccessDenied"
$ Message  : chr "Access Denied"
$ RequestId: chr ""
$ HostId   : chr ""
- attr(*, "headers")=List of 6
..$ x-amz-request-id : chr ""
..$ x-amz-id-2       : chr ""
..$ content-type     : chr "application/xml"
..$ transfer-encoding: chr "chunked"
..$ date             : chr "Tue, 05 Sep 2017 13:23:42 GMT"
..$ server           : chr "AmazonS3"
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
- attr(*, "class")= chr "aws_error"
- attr(*, "request_canonical")= chr "GET\n/"| __truncated__
- attr(*, "request_string_to_sign")= car ""| __truncated__
- attr(*, "request_signature")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=| 
__truncated__
NULL

Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

Any solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I am having similar problem. Did you figure out a solution for this ?

Comment: @T-jay did you manage to solve this, or kindly mark the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your IAM account is not authorized to do that operation.
If you're the owner of the AWS account, you can go to AWS Service IAM, click on users, choose this IAM user and add the necessary authorizations to it.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message when attempting

```r
get_bucket("collidr-api")
```

All I needed to do was add the region name like so

```r
get_bucket("collidr-api", region="asia-south-01")
```

Then it worked. I found that info [here](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/176#issuecomment-357907230).

Answer (score 1):

@audiracmichelle, @Prakhar, use the function `put_object` from aws.s3 library as shown below. The `object` input argument to function put_object is the name(string) the object should have in s3.

You can first write a serialized object (in this case `data`) from memory with:

```
in_mem_obj <- rawConnection(raw(0), "w")
utils::write.table(data, in_mem_obj, sep = "\t", na = "", quote = TRUE, 
                   row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

Then save object to S3 bucket:

```
put_object(rawConnectionValue(in_mem_obj),
           object = FILEPATH/FILENAME,
           bucket = BUCKET,
           headers = c('x-amz-server-side-encryption' = 'AES256'),
           key = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
           secret = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
           region = AWS_REGION,
           check_region = FALSE)
```

Comment: Great, i'm deploying a shiny app on shiny app io, nothing worked so far but your solution. Thanks man i owe you